# Html Theme Integration in Vuetify

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3, ipyvuetify

Can I import CSS and JavaScript files to Vuetify for importing some components?  Or Can I put an entire theme that would be a basic HTML theme?

For example, I found a tool that is needed in the project can I integrate it with Vuetify such as `Datatables`, `JS validation Plugins`, or some statistical widgets, even an entire theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuetify is a UI CSS framework.
So it will grant you some CSS components.

You can add pretty much what you want to it. It will have the issue of needing an overwrite in specific places (CSS cascade/specificity mainly).
But otherwise, nothing special will block you from using it alongside other things.

Comment: @hoorIqbal did it solved your issue?

Comment: actually i imported sass file but there is an error ...........Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/src/assets/css/custom.scss' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Comment: @hoorIqbal is your server running? Check that error on Google.